# Close the Dialog fromo IHostPageLayoutService from azure-devops-extension-sdk

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure-devops, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create a dialog box. Once I have created, how do I close it programmatically?
I'm opening the dialog box with below code.

```js
      const dialogSVC: IHostPageLayoutService = await getService<IHostPageLayoutService>(
        CommonServiceIds.HostPageLayoutService
    );
    
         dialogSVC.openMessageDialog(message, {
                 lightDismiss: false, showCancel: _showCancel, title: "Codespaces Extension"});
```

Any method available to close the opened dialog box?